# Xcode 10.1 beta 2 Invalid Toolchain

Tags: xcode, xcode10.1

I am going to submit my app to App Store and it finds invalid toolchain .

New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions. Xcode 9 or later.

Should I reinstall Xcode 10 GM directly instead of beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must use a stable release of Xcode to submit a build to App Store:

- Xcode 10.1 (10B61)
- Xcode 10 (10A255)
- Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)
- ...

i.e. the versions in **bold** from this unofficial list: https://xcodereleases.com/

Beta versions of Xcode are only good for TestFlight builds, not App Store builds.

Not also that there is a minimum Xcode version depending on your product platform (iOS, tvOS, macOS): https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036